# Automated inventory management using Amazon web services is possible?

Tags: amazon-mws, amazon-marketplace, amazonsellercentral

I have these requirements , Is it possible to accomplish using Amazon Web Services.

I need to get a file (excel) from email address with product numbers (SKUs) and quantities for each one.

I need to load it into database where I already have all inventory for each product.

Then I need to call Amazon Seller Central API to update quantities for all products that I have listed on Amazon store.

Is this possible to do with Amazon Web Services ?

I have gone through https://developer.amazonservices.com/?&ld=NSGoogleAS , But could not find anything useful for my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

"Amazon Web Services" is a big category. You could make an EC2 instance running Windows with Excel installed and hooked up to do everything you want.

There's no ready-made "ETL this Excel file I'm emailing you" service for you. You'll have to do most of the hard work yourself. What AWS can get you is some robustness: have one job that handles checking email and dumping the Excel file onto S3. Make the S3 PutObject action trigger a SQS message. Write some code to poll SQS, parse the Excel file, dump it into the DB, and post another SQS message. Write some more code to poll the second queue and post your updates. Now you can scale out or safely lose bits of your service.

If you're not doing enough work for that to sound appealing, you may want to look for something cheaper than AWS (a discount VPS).

Comment: Geting the excel file from email, parsing it, loading the data into DB , I can all do through java, I just want to know is there any web service in Amazon Seller Central API to update quantities for all products that I have listed on Amazon store?

Comment: Maybe you want to rewrite your question or ask a different one. It sounds like what you're asking has nothing to do with AWS at all and you're just worndering about the Amazon Seller Central API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Flat File Inventory Loader Feed](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_FeedType.html) (Enumeration value: *_POST_FLAT_FILE_INVLOADER_DATA_*)